# Classes for which the Spectrum determines a Convex Shape

Tags: reference-request, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, isospectrality, shape-theory

Given a planar domain $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^2$ bounded and open we can associate to it the spectrum of the Laplace operator with Dirichlet boundary condition. It is known that there are planar domains which are essentially different, but share the same spectrum. The known isospectral domains are not convex, and I think that there are no known isospectral convex domains.

Still, there are a few cases in which the spectrum determines (up to a rigid motion) the shape. For instance we have the circles and rectangles.

> Are there other classes for which we know that the spectrum completely determines the shape?
>
> Are there any results on "almost isospectral convex domains"? (i.e. the fact that $\lambda_k(\Omega_1)=\lambda_k(\Omega_2)$ for $k \leq n$ can say something about the resemblance of the convex sets $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$)

If you know any good references on these matters, please share them.

---

After doing the suggested search I found the following results:

- triangles: http://www.ams.org/notices/201311/rnoti-p1440.pdf
- axisymmetric smooth domains, smooth domains with dihedral symmetry: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0111078.pdf

Comment: Google 'hearing the shape of a triangle' for a proof that a triangle is determined by its spectrum

Comment: @OtisChodosh: Thanks. I have found a few interesting articles.

Comment: Nice question by the way! Here's a related open problem which I think is quite nice (sort of related to your "almost isospectral" question for $k=1$): What is the Faber-Krahn (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh%E2%80%93Faber%E2%80%93Krahn_inequality) inequality on polygons? In other words, what $n$-gon of fixed area minimizes the first Dirichlet eigenfunction? For $n=3,4$ (triangles, quadrilaterals) it is known that the minimizer is the regular $n$-gon. Polya and Szego conjectured that this holds for $n\geq 5$ but very little progress has been made!

Comment: The following paper contains some information about it (and some related questions): http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.em/1175789762&page=record

Comment: @OtisChodosh: I was doing some numerical computations yesterday on exactly the same thing (Faber-Krahn for polygons), obtaining regular polygons, as expected.

Comment: well,i am thinking the same problem and i think we don't own all the tool to deal with this,for example,we know in dimension 4 ,there is two weyl shambles convex,isospectral but not isometry,what is the difference between dim 2 and dim 4?